# Calculate $2^{-1000000}(\frac{5+3\sqrt{3}}{i}-\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{3}i})^{999999}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

what's an easy way to calculate

$2^{-1000000}(\frac{5+3\sqrt{3}}{i}-\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{3}i})^{999999}$ ?

My idea is that it must somehow be possible to merge -1000000 and 999999 to 1, but I just can't figure out what to do!

I would be glad if someone could solve this riddle!

Comment: Are you sure the first term inside the parenthesis is a sum divided by $i$? Is it not $5+3\sqrt{3}i$ or something like that?

Comment: write the complex number inside the parenthesis in polar coordinates i.e. $z=re^{i \theta}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: write the complex part as $|r|e^{i\theta}$. Then taking the power will simply result in $|r|^{9999999}e^{i999999\theta}$.

It's not actually a riddle, just not really useful question...

Answer (score 0):

It's not a riddle. To only way to take exponents together is when the bases are equal. Since 2 does not equal the other big complex number, you cant simplify this expression much.